# issue with $watch on factory object

Tags: angularjs, controller, factory, watch

I have a variable `socialRegisterFactory.pages` set up in my factory that updates once information from FaceBook is fully loaded. I'm trying to $watch this variable in my controller so that when the info is loaded and when that variable changes from false to true, the watch function updates the scope accordingly. I've logged out the factory's variable in the controller and it does show correctly, but the scope is not updating properly. Is there something wrong with my $watch function?

My controller:

```
    $scope.pagesLoaded = false;

    $scope.$watch(socialRegisterFactory.pages, function(newVal, oldVal){
        if (socialRegisterFactory.pages === true) {
            alert("true!");
            $scope.pagesLoaded = true;
        }
    }, true);
```

My factory:

```
    var socialRegisterFactory ={
        pages: false,
        getAvailablePages: function($scope){
            return $http.get(settings.urlBase+'social/facebook/pages')
                .then(function(resp) {
                    socialRegisterFactory.pages = true;
                    angular.copy(resp.data.data, socialRegisterFactory.fbPages);
                    //$scope.fbPages = socialRegisterFactory.fbPages;
                    return  socialRegisterFactory.fbPages;
                });
        },
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The first parameter to your $scope.$watch can either be a string or a function.

[Angular docs here](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/$rootScope.Scope#Parameters).

Not sure this will work in your specific case, but hey.

e.g.

```
$scope.$watch(
  function() { return socialRegisterFactory.pages; },
  function(newVal, oldVal) {
    if (socialRegisterFactory.pages === true) {
        alert("true!");
        $scope.pagesLoaded = true;
    }
  }, 
  true
);
```

Comment: or $scope.$watch('socialRegisterFactory.pages', function(newVal, oldVal){

Comment: @wbeange actually not so sure about that, unless the factory is stored as a reference in $scope.

Comment: Ah yes, you're right the factory would need to be a scope variable